# Do the entropy package in R consider data to be normally distributed for the calculation of mutual information?

Tags: r, entropy

Do the entropy package in R  consider data to be normally distributed for the calculation of mutual information?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: What difference would this make?